# Return isn't executed - Javascript, React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a problem with my function, after calling it inside an `if` statement it works sometimes but it doesn't return the last `return` it starts again with new value.

Here's data I render:

```
 listData: [
    [
      {id: 1, title: 'list1'},
      {id: 2, title: 'list2'},
    ],
    {id: 3, title: 'list3'},
  ];
```

And function:

```
  isArray(a) {
    return (!!a) && (a.constructor === Array);
  }

  renderList(item, options) {
    if (this.isArray(item) === true) {
      item.map((child, childIndex) => {
        this.renderList(child, options)
      })
    }
    return (
      <List item={item} />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Use `Array.isArray`, or an actual polyfill, don't roll your own. Also, the recursive call is unnecessary, just return a div with the lists mapped inside it.

Comment: Your `item.map()` call doesn't have any effect. Even though the children might not be arrays and thus get returned, the result of the `map()` call is discarded.

Comment: @ChrisG what do you suggest?

Comment: @JaredSmith it will be more nested in the future

Comment: @Anna Have you tried the answer below? It works fine. Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6wnn5lxqp3

Answer (score 3):

```
renderList(item, options) {
    if ( Array.isArray(item) ) {
      return item.map( (child, childIndex) => {
        return this.renderList(child, options)
      })
    } else {
      return (
         <List item={item} />
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the answer below. The key point are the missing `return`s.

Comment: More likely yes, but I used `Array.isArray` instead of `this.isArray`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
if (this.isArray(item) === true) {
  return item.map((child, childIndex) => {
    return this.renderList(child, options)
  })
}
```